# JavaScript WYSIWYG equation builder AND function creation

Tags: javascript, math

Is there any easy equation builder (for basic equations - no matrices needed) that not only creates an readable and editable formula but also creates a function that can be called.

[image: Mockup example]

Comment: If I understand you right, you are asking for a WYSIWYG editor that can return a equation that javascript could parse? I'm working for ShareMath, which is a WYSIWYG math editor. But it will return equations in MathML or TeX, and all the editors I know will do the samething.

Comment: Not every equation is a function.

Comment: I know. I'm only requesting whatever that can generate an image of the mathematical equation can make the equivalent JS function.

Comment: i just don understand this question @Norfeldt

Comment: jQuery is important..very important here.

Comment: @PatrickMutwiri I'm not asking for something that looks exactly like this. But could be something like this or an equation editor similar to seen in Word. You then build the equation and in return gets a valid javascript function.

Comment: ok..I like @Norfeldt Its a nice challenge..will check it out...lotsa 'onclick' functions will be there. can i do a simpler one?

Comment: @PatrickMutwiri I'm actually just asking if such a code project already exist. But it doesn't seem as it does. I would be more than happy to get some simple proof of concept code on how this can be archived - then I can build upon that.

Comment: must exist..must be somewhere...I think jce editor plugin is based on that..only that its an editor..

Comment: @Norfeldt https://jsfiddle.net/wyspa6m9/ check it out!

Comment: can I put it as an answer to your question n get the bounty?

Comment: There is a WYSIWYG math editor for TinyMCE called wiris: http://www.wiris.com/en/plugins/moodle/download
It translates equations to several formats, js is not one of them but it could be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are editors to build math functions like you asked, I wanted to give a try to the "create javascript function" part.

My approach was to try to detect any math functions, math constants or variables with a regex, and replace those with the appropiate javascript calls. This assumes you have a math expression like the one in the question image `2 * \pi * r` as an input.

```
var mathExpression = $(this).text();
var variables = [];

function handleElement(match){

    if (match == '\\pi') return "Math.PI";

    // Doesn't match any constant/function --> is a variable
    if (variables.indexOf(match) < 0){
        variables.push(match);      
    }

    return match;
};

var jsExpression = mathExpression.replace(/[^\d\s.+\-*^()]+/g,handleElement);

var result = "var y = function(";
result += variables.join(', ');
result += "){ ";
result += "return ";
result += jsExpression
result += "; }";

console.log(result);
```

Of course, this is only an example solution, and is in no way complete. Depending on the complexity of the functions you want to generate, it might be very difficult (if not impossible) to parse all expressions with this approach. Take for example an expression like `a^2`. You might expect that to be parsed to `Math.pow(a,2)`. While it would be easy to do so when both parameters are a single term, something like this `(2+x)^((2 + x) * 3)` will be difficult to parse, since you'd have to balance the parenthesis to decide what belongs inside the `Math.pow` function.

You can see a working jsfiddle with a couple more functions implemented [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c6811szw/4/).

Comment: Was hoping that there already was something out there, but your code is putting me in the right direction. I think that using building a LaTeX equation and convert it to a string that can be evaluated by [MathJS](http://mathjs.org/) would be one way to go.

Comment: @Norfeldt If that doesn't work, maybe it'd be easier (for complex expressions) to parse from MathML, since there probably are plugins to navigate its xml-like structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is closest to what you asked..javascript calculator. Found it online. tested it and it good. Try it too. You can add functionalities ofcourse..

```
    <div id="display" class="display"></div><ul>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>AC</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>x</li>
    <li>/</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>+</li>
    <li>-</li>
    <li>0</li>
    <li>.</li>
    <li>=</li>
</ul>

    .display {
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 295px;
    text-align: right;
    height: 25px;}ul {
    margin: 0; 
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    width: 335px;}li {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background-color: #555;
    color: White;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;}/**5.12 6.12 0.12 96.12 6.65 6.6* 6.634 Works normally:      1.65, 2.65, 3.65, 8.65, 9.65, 10.65 Innaccurate decimal: 4.65, 5.65, 6.65, 7.65, 
 Works normally:      1.12, 2.12, 3.12, 8.12, 9.12, 10.12 Innaccurate decimal: 4.12, 5.12, 6.12, 7.12, *//     var Calculator = function() {     this.total = 0;     this.current = 0;
    this.operation = null;
    this.fractionExp = 0;
}; Calculator.prototype = {
    add: function() {
        this.calculate();
        this.operation = function(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        };
        this.setCurrent(0, "");
        this.fractionExp = 0; // decimal fix
    },
    subtract: function() {
        this.calculate();
        this.operation = function(a, b) {
            return a - b;
        };
        this.setCurrent(0, "");
        this.fractionExp = 0; // decimal fix
    },
    multiply: function() {
        this.calculate();
        this.operation = function(a, b) {
            return a * b;
        };
        this.setCurrent(0, "");
        this.fractionExp = 0; // decimal fix
    },
    divide: function() {
        this.calculate();
        this.operation = function(a, b) {
            return a / b;
        };
        this.setCurrent(0, "");
        this.fractionExp = 0; // decimal fix
    },
    clear: function() {
        this.setCurrent(0, "");
        this.fractionExp = 0; // decimal fix
    },
    allClear: function() {
        this.clear();
        this.total = 0;
        this.operation = null;
        console.log("total: " + this.total);
        this.fractionExp = 0; // decimal fix
    },
    calculate: function() {
        if (this.operation) {
            this.total = this.operation(this.total, this.current);
        } else {
            this.total = this.current;
        }
        console.log("total: " + this.total);
    },
    equals: function() {
        this.calculate();
        this.updateDisplay(this.total);
    },
    digit: function(number) {
        // shift current left, add number       
        // this is the key the decimal point
        if (this.fractionExp) {
            // not corrent but close
            this.setCurrent(this.current + (number / Math.pow(10, this.fractionExp)));
            this.fractionExp = this.fractionExp + 1
        } else {            
            this.setCurrent((this.current * 10) + number);
        };

    },
    point: function() {
        this.fractionExp = 1;
    },
    setCurrent: function(value, text) {
        this.current = value;
        this.updateDisplay(typeof text == "undefined" ? this.current : text);
        console.log("current: " + this.current);
    },
    updateDisplay: function(value) {
        $("#display").text(value);
    }
};
var calc = new Calculator();
$("li").click(function() {
    var raw = $(this).text()
    number = parseInt(raw, 10);
    if (isNaN(number)) {
        // must be an operator  
        switch (raw) {
        case "C":
            calc.clear();
            break;
        case "AC":
            calc.allClear();
            break;
        case "x":
            calc.multiply();
            break;
        case "/":
            calc.divide();
            break;
        case "+":
            calc.add();
            break;
        case "-":
            calc.subtract();
            break;
        case "=":
            calc.equals();
            break;
        case ".":
            calc.point();
            break;
        }
    } else {
        // its a digit
        calc.digit(number);
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wyspa6m9

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But this isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well I was more looking into something where you can build the equation visually (hence WYSIWYG) and then get a code snippet you can copy into your project. Sorry if I have been unclear. I do appreciate your help!